# Cannot assign "1": "Song.playlist" must be a "Playlist" instance

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add songs to playlists

here is my models.py

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here PlayList is a another model class

Here is my views.py

```
class AddToPlaylist(APIView):
    serializer_class = AddToPlaylistSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.data.get("name")
            artist = serializer.data.get("artist")
            album = serializer.data.get("album")
            playlist = serializer.data.get("playlist")
            print(name, artist, album, playlist)
            song = Song(name=name, artist=artist, album=album, playlist=playlist)
            song.save()
            return Response(SongSerializer(song).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

AddToPlaylistSerializer

```
class AddToPlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Song
    fields = ('name', 'artist', 'album', 'playlist')
```

The `playlist = serializer.data.get("playlist")` seems to returning an Id but i need it to return Playlist intance

Comment: can you please add the PlayList model and serializers

Comment: you are trying to add song in playlist and playlist contain only single song or multiple?

Comment: playlist should contain multiple songs

Comment: bro, then make a proper relationship you made the wrong relation, reference https://www.appsloveworld.com/django/100/277/django-adding-multiple-songs-to-playlist